# setCheck in CheckedTextView don't works

Tags: android

In my app I have a ListView composed by CheckedTextView.
The list is linked to a collection of objects with an int parameter; if that parameter is == 1 then I want that CheckedTextView to be showed already checked.

this is my code:

Activity (it's actually a fragment):

```
ListView lv;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aller_layout, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(rootView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, oggetti);
        lv.setAdapter(ca);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id){
                /*TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;
                Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "Item with id ["+id+"] - Position ["+position+"] - Planet ["+clickedView.getText()+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            }   
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Oggetto>{

    private Context context;
    private Oggetto[] oggetti = null;
    private int layoutid;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutid, Oggetto[] oggetti){
        super(context, layoutid, oggetti);

        this.context = context;
        this.oggetti = oggetti;
        this.layoutid = layoutid;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutid, parent, false);
        }

        Oggetto oggetto = oggetti[position];
        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        ctv.setText(oggetto.nome);
        if(oggetto.preferito == 1)
            ctv.setChecked(true);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The ListView it's showed correctly and I can check any option without problems but the setChecked(true) method don't works.

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked that the data is correct? You can add a `Log.d()` before setting the check and just print out what `(oggetto.preferito == 1)` evaluates to.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that and the app enters in the if (note that right now I'm using a dummy class "Oggetto" just for testing so I'm completely sure abut the content). I also tried to put a Toast inside the if branch to see if it was showed correctly and it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckedTextView` doesn't visibly show that it's checked, it just stores that state internally. You should probably replace it with a `CheckBox`. If you don't want it to be clickable, just add `android:clickable="false"` in your XML.

Comment: Ok, created a custom layout (instead of the android.R) with a CheckBox and not a CheckedTextView and the code works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(oggetto.preferito == 1)
            ctv.setChecked(false);   --> THIS IS WRONG
```

you should

```
   ctv.setChecked(oggetto.preferito == 1);
```